# Read XML for Variables

Tags: xml, parsing, visual-c++

**Background**: So I've created a VC++, MFC application that is basically a large preference dialog where the user can configure a number of pages, each with a bunch of different settings. These pages are then exported to XML files to configure another application. So basically it's a GUI, XML writer.

Since there are so many settings, I really need to be able to support importing settings into the application so that the user doesn't have to re-enter every value each time he/she wants to make a change. I would like to be able to support importing XML files (like the ones that it generates).

I know about XML parsers and how to parse a file for values, but I'm not sure how to approach my current problem because there are hundreds upon hundreds of variables. Time-wise, wouldn't it be slow to search through the XML documents for every variable to find the matching value the call UpdateData(FALSE)? Is there an easier/better/faster solution?

EDIT: Also, I don't want to have to depend on the XML tags being in the same order every time. Technically they would be since *I'm* generating them, but I don't want to assume that.

EDIT 2: Much of the document looks like this...there are *some* divisions, but not enough I don't think.

```
<MAIN_APP>
    <!-- General Configuration -->
    <BARCO_ENABLED>1</BARCO_ENABLED>
    <CHANNEL_COUNT value = "1" />
    <!-- Elevation Data Format: 0 = DTED; 1 = RDTED-->
    <ELEVATION_DATA_FORMAT value = "0" />
    <BLOCKS_PER_FRAME value = "4" />
    <PROCESS_FACTOR value = "0" />
    <!-- Message Processing: 0=Default, 1:Immediate -->
    <IMMEDIATE_MESSAGE_MODE value = "0" />
    <!--Threat Diameter Size In Texels: 0 = 256(default); 1 = 512; 2 = 1024; 3 = 2048 -->
    <THREAT_DIAMETER_TEXEL_COUNT value = "2" />
    <!-- Texture Size: 0 = 256X256 (default); 1 = 512X512; 2 = 1024X1024; 3 = 2048X2048 -->
    <DATAFRAME_TEXTURE_SIZE value = "2" />
    <GEOCHIP_TEXTURE_SIZE value = "0" />
    <OWNSHIP_VISIBILITY_TEXTURE_SIZE value = "2" />
    <!-- If the vehicle sensor texture is not used, it can be set to -1 to avoid allocation -->
    <VEHICLE_SENSOR_TEXTURE_SIZE value = "-1" />
    <!-- Map Timeout: -999 = No Timeout; > 0 = Time out in milliseconds -->
    <MAP_TIMEOUT value = "-999" />
    <!-- Image to use for the Map Standby screen -->
    <MAP_STANDBY_IMAGE value = "/BMP/MAP_STANDBY.bmp" />
    <!-- Maximum Frame Buffer Dimensions (pixels) -->
    <VIEWPORT_WIDTH value = "1024" />
    [ ... ]
</MAIN_APP>
```

Here is an example of a divided section.

```
<ROUTE_REPLAN_SIZE value = "25" />
<ROUTE_MAX_REPLAN_WAYPOINTS value = "5" />
<SYMBOL_RENDER_PRIORITY>
    <TACTICAL      value = "5"  />
    <USER          value = "4"  />
    <DRAWINGFILE   value = "2"  />
    <DVOF          value = "0"  />
    <LOCAL_POINT   value = "3"  />
    <MCHUM         value = "1"  />
    <THREAT_RING   value = "6"  />
    <THREAT_SYMBOL value = "7"  />
    <ARINC_424     value = "8"  />
    <DAFIF         value = "9" />
    <AIRSPACE      value = "10" />
</SYMBOL_RENDER_PRIORITY>
<!-- GeoSymbol Library Configuratoin -->
<GEOSYMBOL_LIBRARY_CONFIG>
    <!-- Predefined Symbol memory value is in KB -->
    <PREDEFINED_SYMBOL_MEMORY     value = "35000" />
    <DYNAMIC_TACTICAL_COUNT       value = "100" />
    <DYNAMIC_USER_GEOSYMBOL_COUNT value = "32" />
    <USER_GEOSYMBOL_SKIN_COUNT    value = "32" />
    <!-- DVOF Label Selection.  Valid Input: 0 = NONE, 1 = AGL, 2 = MSL, 3 = BOTH -->
    <VO_LABEL_DISPLAY             value = "1" />
</GEOSYMBOL_LIBRARY_CONFIG>
```

Comment: Please give a short example so that we can see how your XML doc is structured

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to break your xml into small sections. Every gui form has groups/panels. you can name xml based on *formname-panelname.xml*. Each panel should be mapped on separate hashmap i.e. there should be a hashmap which holds all the values for *formname-panelname*. By doing this, at a given time, you will be modifying one particular hashmap in the memory which is easily searchable. you can add new variables/remove old one and edit the names.

Comment: That's a good idea to break it up. The GUI panels were broken based on the XML groupings (for the most part...there are some exceptions), so this is probably the best way to do it. EDIT: Now that I think about it, it's not divided very well at all...most of the tags are <tags /> and there are few structured groupings and elements. This is for an XML that I did not write, so I'm trying to adapt :\

Comment: I am not sure what is your current focus right now. If you can afford your XML to be in memory at any given time, then XPATH is the best bet at the moment. XPATH gives you flexibility to search any "given" element by writing the absolute/relative path to the root. You wouldn't have to PARSE entire XML to read/write a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're storing key/value pairs in you XML. One simple approach would be to load the whole XML once into some kind of helper-datastructure and then just look for a value for a given key/element. As this would take place in memory, it would be sufficiently fast (provided the datastructure is efficent). You could for example write a function reading all the element_name/value pairs into a hash-table, so you can query by element name very efficiently.

Comment: The data structure is not very efficient as it stands right now. There are some divisions, but for the most part the XML is composed of individual <tags />. It was already written, and they requested this application be made.